# How to update multiple records in one click

Tags: php, mysql

I have 30 records of same ticket id and I want to update records from this array value :

> Array ( [0] => test [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2e9w.png) => test [2] => test [3] => testy [4] => tr [5] => yt [6] => y [7] => y [8] => y [9] => y [10] => y [11] => yu [12] => iui [13] => iu [14] => ii [15] => ii [16] => iii [17] => i [18] => iii [19] => ii [20] => iip [21] => yt [22] => yu [23] => u [24] => u [25] => u [26] => yuy [27] => uy [28] => y [29] => testlast )

but when I am updating, it is updating the last index value in all 30 records.

My code is :

```
for($x = 0; $x < 30; $x++){         
    $update=$database->update(
        "table", 
        ["remarks" => $remark[$x]], 
        ["ticket_id" => $ticketid ]
    );
}
```

This is my table and i want to update record in this table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2e9w.png)

What is missing in my code ?

Comment: You are updating all records for `$ticketid` in every loop. So only the last data is stored. You need to use some other identifier along with `$ticketid`, like `id`.

Comment: How are getting those data?

Comment: @Sougata Bose  the data in array is ,which i have input from textbox for updating

Comment: I have to use ticket id as identifier because in my table ticketid have 30 records, so i need to update first record from first index ,second record from second index and so on.But issue is when i am doing it is updating last index value in all 30 records.

Comment: The table needs to have a primary key. Else it will not be able to identify a particular record. Or you can use the old value of remarks to identify.

Comment: yes table have primary key

Comment: Which one is unique?

Comment: that is auto increament i cant use that for updating

Comment: YOu dont have to update it. Use it in where clause along with ticket_id

Comment: i have to get this "id" from table first?? or can u edit the code?

Comment: @Sougata Bose  yes its done thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try to save it :

```
for($x = 0; $x < 30; $x++){         
    $update=$database->update(
        "table", 
        ["remarks" => $remark[$x]], 
        ["ticket_id" => $ticketid ]
    );
    $update->save();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your change? What does that additional method call do?